# Using multiple UNION ALLs to build a view: is there a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

There are some constraints to this question; I don't have the ability to fundamentally alter any database structure.

The challenge here is that I have rows in a database that contain information that really should be on its own row. A somewhat simplified example of the column structure:

```
[PersonID] [FirstName] [LastName] [FirstNameGuest1] [LastNameGuest1]
 1          Ringo       Starr      John              Lennon
 2          George      Harrison   Paul              McCartney
```

I need to split these out like this in order to be able to run the reports I need:

```
[PersonID] [FirstName] [LastName]
 1          Ringo       Starr
 1          John        Lennon
 2          George      Harrison
 2          Paul        McCartney
```

Since I'm using this to produce a view, I've had to just reference the same table for each group of guest columns and use `UNION ALLs` to tie them all together.

However, since then I've had to build queries of ever-increasing complexity on top of the derived view. Each layer of complexity causes the results to return more and more slowly.

Am I taking a fundamentally bad approach? Are there other, more correct ways to model the data in the way that I need?

Here's part of the actual query so you can see what I'm dealing with:

```
--Primary Record
SELECT
 'Franchisee' AS 'Type', 
 Confirmation AS 'BelongingTo', 
 0 AS 'GuestNo', 
 FirstName, 
 LastName, 
 FF_27557_152972 AS 'HotelChoice', 
 HotelCheckIn, 
 HotelCheckOut, 
 HotelSmoking AS 'Smoking', 
 (CASE FF_27554_1 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'PrimaryRoomHolder', 
 '' AS 'SharingWith', 
 'None' AS 'SharingWithName'
FROM dbo.[Table]
WHERE Type = 'Production' AND Submitted = 1 AND Cancelled = 0 AND Label = 'Primary'

UNION ALL
-- First Guest
SELECT
'Guest' AS 'Type',
Confirmation AS 'BelongingTo',
1 AS 'GuestNo', 
FF_27637_1 AS 'FirstName', 
FF_27637_152806 AS 'LastName', 
FF_27637_152822 AS 'HotelChoice', 
FF_27637_152813 AS 'HotelCheckIn', 
FF_27637_152821 AS 'HotelCheckOut', 
FF_27637_152824 AS 'Smoking', 
(CASE WHEN FF_27637_152822 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'PrimaryRoomHolder', 
FF_27637_154245 AS 'SharingWith', 
(CASE CAST(FF_27637_154245 AS integer) 
  WHEN 0 THEN FirstName + ' ' + LastName 
  WHEN 1 THEN FF_27637_1 + ' ' + FF_27637_152806 
  WHEN 2 THEN FF_27742_1 + ' ' + FF_27742_153577 
  WHEN 3 THEN FF_27638_1 + ' ' + FF_27638_152814 
  WHEN 4 THEN FF_27639_1 + ' ' + FF_27639_152817 
  WHEN 5 THEN FF_27640_1 + ' ' + FF_27640_152852
  WHEN 6 THEN FF_27641_1 + ' ' + FF_27641_152860 
  WHEN 7 THEN FF_27642_1 + ' ' + FF_27642_152868 
  WHEN 8 THEN FF_27643_1 + ' ' + FF_27643_152877
  WHEN 9 THEN FF_27644_1 + ' ' + FF_27644_152885 
  WHEN 10 THEN FF_27645_1 + ' ' + FF_27645_152893 
  ELSE 'None' END) AS 'SharingWithName'
FROM dbo.Event_213_1546 AS Event_213_1546_10
WHERE Type = 'Production' AND Submitted = 1 AND Cancelled = 0 AND Label = 'Primary' AND FF_27637_1 IS NOT NULL
.
.
.
(Iterates through 9 more guests exactly like "First Guest")
```

Comment: I can feel your pain there... x_X.

Comment: Is there big issues with performance related to the query or are you just wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: I feel your pain since you can't change the database structure, but truly that is the best solution to your problem. You need a related table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered the UNPIVOT operator? It does the same thing, but might be less painful (maybe! :-). Requires 2005 or later.

http://blogs.msdn.com/craigfr/archive/2007/07/17/the-unpivot-operator.aspx

Example:

```
declare @names table ( personid int, 
    firstname1 varchar(50), 
    lastname1 varchar(50),
    firstname2 varchar(50), 
    lastname2 varchar(50),
    firstname3 varchar(50), 
    lastname3 varchar(50)

    -- <etc.>
    )

Insert @names values ( 1, 'Fred', 'Flintstone', 'Barney', 'Rubble', 'Wilma', 'Flintstone' )
Insert @names values ( 2, 'Super', 'Man', 'Aqua', 'Man', 'Wonder', 'Woman' )

select * from @names

select personid, firstnamecol, firstname, lastnamecol, lastname
from @names
unpivot( firstname for firstnamecol in ( firstname1, firstname2, firstname3 ) ) firstnames
unpivot( lastname for lastnamecol in ( lastname1, lastname2, lastname3 ) ) lastnames
where right(firstnamecol, 1) = right( lastnamecol, 1 ) -- This is the tricky bit
```

Using multiple unpivots in one select is tricky; I got the above notion from these guys:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/04/23/unpivot.aspx 
http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html

It's important to note that the part marked "tricky" will break with varying numbers of digits in the names of the repeating columns (e.g. FirstName11 and FirstName1 will be a problem). You could work around that with some substring() tricks. Might not be the best idea, but...

Addition, Feb 22: This is a PHENOMENAL article on unpivot: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/02/spotlight-on-unpivot-part-1.html

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the unpivot operator. Conceptually, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Just be careful - I don't know what sort of performance impact you can expect. Could be terrible :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are trying to do with the view.
The view query has to execute before whatever operations you perform on it.  So if you are doing things that only deal with 10% of the results returned by the view, there's a waste of processing.  It's likely the operations performed could be done at the same time as the logic already in the view.

Can you add indexes if necessary?  That would help...

A materialized view, called an [indexed view in SQL Server terminology](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx), is a viable possibility but notoriously unaccommodating.

Comment: Technically, views do not necessarily "execute before" other operations. In fact, I believe views are expanded in the context of an enclosing query and then the whole business gets optimized as one plan. Exceptions would be when using the "noexpand" hint.

Comment: @onupdatecascade: In order for operations to occur on the resultset provided by a view, the view has to execute first.  Effectively, a subquery/derived table.  `SELECT LEFT(...) FROM v_view` has to run the view query first - the view query is not interrupted to add the additional criteria.

Comment: Curious, I've run select statements on views that run faster if I omit a choice column from the view (This column is based on a poorly designed UDF.). If the view is required to run first, they would perform the same?

Comment: It's plausible that the query runs faster because you omitted the column afterwards - the query plan would already exist.  The first time would have been the hard parse, subsequent ones are soft parses.

Comment: @OMGPonies - it depends on the content of the view, and the rules for optimization. If there's a function in there (like your left() example) then it might be necessary to process all the rows in the view, but that's because of the function, not the presence of the  view. The rules for optimization would be the same if you copied and pasted the view definition into the outer query as a derived table.

Comment: See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx "Using the NOEXPAND view hint" This can be proven with some query plan examination

Answer (score 1):

Here are the results of implementing the answer I accepted above. Hopefully this will be helpful to anyone following this who faces a similar challenge.

Conceptually, the UNPIVOT operator models exactly what I'm trying to accomplish; it remained to be seen if it didn't have some sort of implementation limitation that would keep me from being able to use it. Since I had many columns to 'unpack,' there were two basic approaches to using the UNPIVOT operator. **(1)** I could run a separate UNPIVOT for each column in question, or **(2)**, I could run one UNPIVOT and then conditionally calculate the rest of the columns based on that result. I chose the second approach because it was a little easier for me to grasp, but I'm still interested to test the two against each other in the future.

The resultant query is still inelegantly repetitious (it has to keep doing the same ten-condition case block over and over) but it's unbelievably simplified compared the monstrosity I was working with originally. **Most importantly, when I run this in line with the old query, it's only 9% of the total query cost, vs. 91% from the old query.** So it appears to be much more efficient as well.

Here's the reworked query (still long, but probably only about 20% of the length of the old one)

```
SELECT
    Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Guest' END as RegType,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN 0
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN 1
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN 2
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN 3
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN 4
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN 5
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN 6
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN 7
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN 8
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN 9
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN 10 END) as GuestNo,  
    Confirmation, 
    FirstNames as FirstName,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN LastName
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_152806
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27742_153577
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27638_152814
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27639_152817
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27640_152852
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27641_152860
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27642_152868
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27643_152877
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27644_152885
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27645_152893 END) as LastName,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN Email
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_152807
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27742_153578
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27638_152815
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27639_152818
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27640_152853
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27641_152861
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27642_152869
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27643_152878
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27644_152886
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27645_152894 END) as Email,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN HotelCheckOut
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_152821
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27645_152896
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27742_153580
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27638_152847
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27639_152842
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27640_152855
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27641_152863
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27642_152871
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27643_152880
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27644_152888 END) as HotelChoice,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN HotelCheckIn
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_152813
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27742_153579
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27638_152816
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27639_152819
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27640_152854
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27641_152862
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27642_152870
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27643_152879
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27644_152887
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27645_152895 END) as HotelCheckIn,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN HotelCheckOut
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_152821
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27742_153580
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27638_152847
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27639_152842
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27640_152855
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27641_152863
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27642_152871
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27643_152880
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27644_152888
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27645_152896 END) as HotelCheckOut,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN HotelRoomPreference
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_152823
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27742_153582
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27638_152849
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27639_152844
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27640_152857
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27641_152865
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27642_152874
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27643_152882
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27644_152890
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27645_152898 END) as RoomType,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN HotelSmoking
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_152824
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27742_153583
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27638_152850
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27639_152845
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27640_152858
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27641_152866
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27642_152875
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27643_152883
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27644_152891
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27645_152899 END) as Smoking,
    (Case(FN) WHEN 'FirstName' THEN NULL
        WHEN 'FF_27637_1' THEN FF_27637_154245
        WHEN 'FF_27742_1' THEN FF_27742_154247
        WHEN 'FF_27638_1' THEN FF_27638_154249
        WHEN 'FF_27639_1' THEN FF_27639_154251
        WHEN 'FF_27640_1' THEN FF_27640_154253
        WHEN 'FF_27641_1' THEN FF_27641_154255
        WHEN 'FF_27642_1' THEN FF_27642_154257
        WHEN 'FF_27643_1' THEN FF_27643_154259
        WHEN 'FF_27644_1' THEN FF_27644_154261
        WHEN 'FF_27645_1' THEN FF_27645_154263 END) as SharingWith,

FROM Event
UNPIVOT (FirstNames for FN in (FirstName, FF_27637_1, FF_27742_1, FF_27638_1, FF_27639_1, FF_27640_1, FF_27641_1, FF_27642_1, FF_27643_1, FF_27644_1, FF_27645_1)) as FirstNames
WHERE Audience = 'Primary' and Submitted = 1 and Cancelled = 0 and Type = 'Production' ORDER BY Confirmation
```

As a side note, if I try to run this as a view, I get an error that UNPIVOT is not supported. If I put the same thing in a view and make it a derived table –`SELECT * FROM (...query...)`)–, I get the same warning in Studio Manager, but it returns the results just fine. Weird.

Thanks again for all your answers.